# JavaScript Classes and Modules in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am having a hard time understanding how can I import a separate .js file into my index.js node file.

I created a file pokemon.js as shown below:

```
var pokemon = (function(){

  function Pokemon(name) {

    this.name = name; 
    console.log("pokemon");
  }

})();

module.exports.Pokemon = pokemon;
```

And now in my index.js I want to use it:

```
var Pokemon = require('./models/pokemon.js');
```

// how do I call the Pokemon function?

**UPDATE**:

```
var Pokemon = require('./models/models.js');
var app = express();

var pokemons = [];

app.get("/pokemon/all",function(req,res){

  var pokemon = Pokemon("Pikachu"); // Pokemon is not a function



})
```

**Here is the solution that I found:**

models.js:

```
module.exports = function(name) {
  this.name = name; 
}

index.js: 

var Pokemon = require('./models/models.js');
var app = express();

var pokemons = [];

app.get("/pokemon/all",function(req,res){

  var pokemon = new Pokemon('Pikachu');
  pokemons.push(pokemon);
  res.json(pokemons);

})
```

Comment: Your IIFE doesn't return anything, so `pokemon` is `undefined`.

Comment: Remove the IIFE part and make `pokemon = function Pokemon...`.

Comment: Can you write is as an answer so I have better idea? What if pokemon has methods or functions.

Comment: @johndoe You should answer your own question with the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you want to export the object constructor.

**pokemon.js**

```
function Pokemon(name){
   this.name = name;
   console.log(this.name);
}
// if any prototype
Pokemon.prototype.serviceOne = function(){ };
Pokemon.prototype.serviceTwo = function(){ };


module.exports = Pokemon;
```

**index.js**

```
var Pokemon = require('path/to/pokemon'); 
app.get("/pokemon/all",function(req,res){

    var pikachu= new Pokemon("Pikachu"); 
    pikachu.serviceOne();
    pikachu.serviceTwo();

})
```

Comment: I am getting the same thing. Pokemon is not defined. Also using the above approach how do you add functions to the Pokemon class (function).

Comment: @johndoe export as constructor. Edited.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

the provided by @catta just have a little bug try :

```
var pokemon = function(name) {
this.name = name; 
console.log("pokemon");
}
module.exports.Pokemon = pokemon;
```

in the index.js

```
var Pokemon = require('./models.js'); 
Pokemon.Pokemon('name') //output name
```

Comment: Still getting undefined.

Comment: the last line look it :

   Pokemon.Pokemon("name");

Its not 
    Pokemon("name");
Or Paste current code

Comment: just tried it in my laptop @john-doe 

`b07/apps/test/over$ more models.js 
var pokemon = function(name) {
    this.name = name; 
    console.log("pokemon");
  }
  module.exports.Pokemon = pokemon; 
douxsey@douxsey-CR70-2M-CX70-2OC-CX70-2OD:/mnt/9aa1c3fe-f4e9-4867-afef-8ab2db92eb07/apps/test/over$ more index.js 
var Pokemon = require('./models.js'); 
Pokemon.Pokemon('name') //output name
douxsey@douxsey-CR70-2M-CX70-2OC-CX70-2OD:/mnt/9aa1c3fe-f4e9-4867-afef-8ab2db92eb07/apps/test/over$ node index.js 
pokemon
`

Comment: Good Solutions too.

Answer (score 0):

**pokemon.js**

```
var pokemon = function(str){
    this.name = str; 
    console.log(this.name);
};
module.exports.Pokemon = pokemon;
```

**main.js**

```
var Pokemon = require('./models/models.js');
var app = express();
var pokemons = [];
app.get("/pokemon/all",function(req,res){
  pokemons.push(Pokemon.Pokemon("Pikachu"));
})
```

When you set var key to require it just references to that file. Therefore you need "Pokemon.Pokemon()"

Comment: If I am using the above technique how can I add Prototype functions to my Pokemon object.

Comment: You can:
`pokemon.prototype.f = function() { }`